# Query large list of metadate in weaviate

Tags: metadata, weaviate

I have 100.000 images, each of them have 500 orb vectors, and each image has a unique tag.

My general issue is, when I insert a new image (i.e. 500 new vectors), how can I know if the image's tag is already in the database ?

What I do is to attache to each vector a metadata "tag". In can retrieve the inserted tags with

```
    result = client.query.get('orb_vector', ['tag'])\
        .with_limit(200)\
        .do()
```

This provides more or less 200 tags among the 100.000 existing.

Accordingly to [the documentation](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/filters.html#performance-and-resource-considerations--limitations), that way of doing is not scalable.

How do I do ?

Context:

- My database is not very dynamic; apart of the initial big insertion (100.000+ images), there will be few insertions each day. So I'm okay with a request taking 5 minutes and keeping the result in memory in a non-dynamic way. Plain python list is okay.
- Clarification: each image has one tag, but 500 vectors. So each tag is present 500 times in the database.
- I'm using python.

What I can do:

Writing the list of tags in a json/mongo/other and reading/updating it each time I insert new images.
I prefer to avoid this solution since the synchronization between the weaviate database and the json will just be a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered creating a separate class for the tags and using query filters?

For example, define a schema for a class named Tag where:

1. it has a property called "name" to store the tag's name e.g. outdoors, indoors, etc
2. it has a property called "images" to store the [cross references](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/schema/datatypes.html#datatype-cross-reference) to the images that are tagged with "outdoors".

Then, when you want to insert an image with tag "car", for example, you do a [WHERE filter](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/filters.html#where-filter) on the Tag class where the name name is `Equal` to "car".

If the result is empty, then that tag does not exist.